# How to connect to zabbix server using java API

Tags: zabbix, java

I am trying to connect to a Zabbix server. I am able to access the Zabbix server running on port 10051 via the web browser, however, I am unable to connect to the same server using Java API. Following is the code that I am using to connect

```
import io.github.cgi.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi;
import io.github.cgi.zabbix.api.ZabbixApi;

public class TestClass {

ZabbixApi zabbixApi;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    tc.before();
    tc.testLogin();
    // tc.testVersion();
}

public void before() {
    String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10051/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php";
    zabbixApi = new DefaultZabbixApi(url);
    zabbixApi.init();
}

public void testLogin() {
    String user = "admin";
    String password = "zabbix";
    boolean login = zabbixApi.login(user, password);
    System.out.println("login result:" + login);
}

public void testVersion() {
    String version = zabbixApi.apiVersion();
    System.err.println(version);
    System.out.println("version := " + version);
}

}
```

Classpath is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/zabbix-api-0.0.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/httpclient-4.5.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/jackson-all-1.9.9.jar/jackson-all-1.9.9.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/httpcore-4.4.8.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/commons-logging-1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Software_Development/Jars/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
```

Error while running this code is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: DefaultZabbixApi call exception!
at io.github.cgi.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi.call(DefaultZabbixApi.java:142)
at io.github.cgi.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi.login(DefaultZabbixApi.java:72)
at TestClass.testLogin(TestClass.java:25)
at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:839)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at io.github.cgi.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi.call(DefaultZabbixApi.java:138)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:286)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:207)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
... 7 more
```

Need help in connecting to Zabbix server using Java API.

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting to the zabbix-server (port 10051). API is a part of zabbix-frontend, so please connect to your web server (port depends on your web server configuration, usually 80).

Comment: Or 443 when using https

Answer (score 0):

change the below URL to port 80 or on which zabbix was running.

String url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10051/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php";